# Как разобраться с кракозябрами в отладке

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться. Установил плагин code runner для visual studio code, однако, когда выводил результат функции, то вместо числа 7, мне выводит незакодированные символы. Как это исправить?

Comment: какая кодировка стоит в окружении?

Comment: у меня стоит кодировка utf-8

Comment: точно `ru_RU.UTF-8`? что-то я сомневаюсь... А где вы смотрели LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE или LC_CTYPE или просто в LANG?

Comment: Выполните команду `set` в терминале и скопируйте вывод, добавьте сюда в вопрос